# How to disable slicing in C++?

Tags: c++, object-slicing

Could slicing be disabled in C++ using any environment variable or any cflags options?

Is any way to disable it by default?

Comment: I think this is relevant to the question: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/object-slicing-in-c

Comment: short answer: move the copy constructor and assignment operator to private or tag with delete.  Or just use references and pointers instead of assignment by value.

Comment: What do you mean with disable? Do you want a compiler error if there is objects slicing somewhere in your code??

Answer (score 3):

No -- object slicing is an unavoidable consequence of C++'s pass-by-value/copy semantics and can't be avoided except by not trying to copy a subclass object to a superclass-object.

The way to deal with unwanted object-slicing is to avoid copying; use pass-by-reference instead, or if you absolutely must have an unsliced/polymorphic copy of an object (e.g. because you're going to want to modify the copy and don't want to modify the original) you'll need to implement some kind of `virtual std::unique_ptr<BaseClass> clone() const` method on your objects, so that you can call `clone()` on the object you want to copy and have `clone()` dynamically allocate, copy-construct, and return-by-pointer a copy of itself that includes all the correct subclass data.

Comment: It can also be avoided by overloading constructors to give a compilation error for an attempted slice